# understanding math errors in pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, ipython

I'm trying to generate a new column in a pandas dataframe from other columns and am getting some math errors that I don't understand.  Here is a snapshot of the problem and some simplifying diagnostics...

I can generate a data frame that looks pretty good:

```
import pandas
import math as m

data = {'loc':['1','2','3','4','5'],
        'lat':[61.3850,32.7990,34.9513,14.2417,33.7712],
        'lng':[-152.2683,-86.8073,-92.3809,-170.7197,-111.3877]}
frame = pandas.DataFrame(data)

frame

Out[15]:
lat lng loc
0    61.3850    -152.2683    1
1    32.7990     -86.8073    2
2    34.9513     -92.3809    3
3    14.2417    -170.7197    4
4    33.7712    -111.3877    5
5 rows × 3 columns
```

I can do simple math (i.e. degrees to radians):

```
In [32]:
m.pi*frame.lat/180.

Out[32]:
0    1.071370
1    0.572451
2    0.610015
3    0.248565
4    0.589419
Name: lat, dtype: float64
```

But I can't convert from degrees to radians using the python math library:

```
 In [33]:
 m.radians(frame.lat)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-99a986252f80> in <module>()
----> 1 m.radians(frame.lat)

/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.pyc in wrapper(self)
     72             return converter(self.iloc[0])
     73         raise TypeError(
---> 74             "cannot convert the series to {0}".format(str(converter)))
     75     return wrapper
     76 

TypeError: cannot convert the series to <type 'float'>
```

And can't even convert the values to floats to try to force it to work:

```
In [34]:

float(frame.lat)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-3311aee92f31> in <module>()
----> 1 float(frame.lat)

/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.pyc in wrapper(self)
     72             return converter(self.iloc[0])
     73         raise TypeError(
---> 74             "cannot convert the series to {0}".format(str(converter)))
     75     return wrapper
     76 

TypeError: cannot convert the series to <type 'float'>
```

I'm sure there must be a simple explanation and would appreciate your help in finding it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

math functions such as [math.radians](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.radians) expect a numeric value such as a float, not a sequence such as a `pandas.Series`.

Instead, you could use [numpy.radians](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.radians.html), since `numpy.radians` can accept an array as input:

```
In [95]: np.radians(frame['lat'])
Out[95]: 
0    1.071370
1    0.572451
2    0.610015
3    0.248565
4    0.589419
Name: lat, dtype: float64
```

---

Only Series of length 1 can be converted to a `float`. So while
this works,

```
In [103]: math.radians(pd.Series([1]))
Out[103]: 0.017453292519943295
```

in general it does not:

```
In [104]: math.radians(pd.Series([1,2]))
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <type 'float'>
```

---

`math.radians` is calling `float` on its argument. Note that you get the same error calling `float` on `pd.Series([1,2])`:

```
In [105]: float(pd.Series([1,2]))
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <type 'float'>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue but was using a custom function. The solution was to use the `apply` function:

```
def monthdiff(x):
    z = (int(x/100) * 12) + (x - int(x/100) * 100)
    return z

series['age'].apply(monthdiff)
```

Now, I have a new column with my simple (yet beautiful) calculation applied to every line in the data frame!

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
pd.to_numeric()
```

When I got the same error, this is what worked for me.