# Google Location distance calculation using python dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, google-location-services

I am trying to tease out the dates that I was in a certain area (within a mile or so) using Google Location data and Python Pandas Dataframe.

First convert to latitude from latitudeE7:

```
with open(Takeout_google_location_history) as f:
data = json.loads(f.read())

df = json_normalize(data['locations'])
df['latitudeE7'] = df['latitudeE7'].div(10000000.0)
df['longitudeE7'] = df['longitudeE7'].div(10000000.0)
df.head()
```

Then calculate the distance:

```
import haversine as hs
from haversine import Unit
loc1 = (31.393300,-99.070050)
df['diff'] = hs.haversine(loc1,(df['latitudeE7'],df['longitudeE7']),unit=Unit.MILES)
df.head()
```

And getting this error:

```
~\Anaconda2\envs\notebook\lib\site-packages\haversine\haversine.py in 
haversine(point1, point2, unit)
     92     lat1 = radians(lat1)
     93     lng1 = radians(lng1)
---> 94     lat2 = radians(lat2)
     95     lng2 = radians(lng2)
     96 

~\Anaconda2\envs\notebook\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in             wrapper(self)
    183         if len(self) == 1:
    184             return converter(self.iloc[0])
--> 185         raise TypeError(f"cannot convert the series to {converter}")
    186 
    187     wrapper.__name__ = f"__{converter.__name__}__"

TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>
```

I am not sure what to do with the data to make it a float.

I have tried:

```
df['latitudeE7'] = df['latitudeE7'].div(10000000.0).astype(float)
```

As well as using a hand written distance:

```
import math
def distance(origin, destination):

  lat1, lon1 = origin
  lat2, lon2 = destination
  radius = 6371  # km

  dlat = math.radians(float(lat2) - lat1)
  dlon = math.radians(float(lon2) - lon1)
  a = (math.sin(dlat / 2) * math.sin(dlat / 2) +
     math.cos(math.radians(lat1)) * math.cos(math.radians(lat2)) *
     math.sin(dlon / 2) * math.sin(dlon / 2))
  c = 2 * math.atan2(math.sqrt(a), math.sqrt(1 - a))
  d = radius * c

  return d
```

Still getting the same error:

```
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_22916/3664391511.py in distance(origin, destination)
     26     radius = 6371  # km
     27 
---> 28     dlat = math.radians(float(lat2) - lat1)
     29     dlon = math.radians(float(lon2) - lon1)
     30     a = (math.sin(dlat / 2) * math.sin(dlat / 2) +

~\Anaconda2\envs\notebook\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in wrapper(self)
    183         if len(self) == 1:
    184             return converter(self.iloc[0])
--> 185         raise TypeError(f"cannot convert the series to {converter}")
    186 
    187     wrapper.__name__ = f"__{converter.__name__}__"

TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>
```

Comment: qh - answer helped a lot. The final answer was "df['diff'] = df.apply(lambda row: hs.haversine(loc1, (row['latitudeE7'], row['longitudeE7']), unit=Unit.MILES), axis=1)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly pass pd.Series to `haversine` function.

### Code:

```py
from haversine import haversine, Unit
import pandas as pd

loc1 = (31.393300, -99.070050)

# Sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'latitudeE7': [0, 0], 'longitudeE7': [0, 0]})

# Calculation
# df['diff'] = haversine(loc1, (df['latitudeE7'], df['longitudeE7']), unit=Unit.MILES) # This doesn't work
df['diff'] = df.apply(lambda row: haversine(loc1, (row['latitudeE7'], row['longitudeE7']), unit=Unit.MILES), axis=1)
```

### Output:

| latitudeE7 | longitudeE7 | diff |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 6752.74 |
| 0 | 0 | 6752.74 |

### Reference:

The issue you have seems related to the following post: [understanding math errors in pandas dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23748842/understanding-math-errors-in-pandas-dataframes)

---

## [EDIT]

If the number of rows is large, `haversin_vector` will be the proper method in terms of speed.

### Code

#### # Preparation:

```py
from haversine import haversine, haversine_vector, Unit
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

loc1 = (31.393300, -99.070050)

# Sample dataframe
n = 1000000
df = pd.DataFrame({'latitudeE7': np.random.rand(n) * 180 - 90, 'longitudeE7': np.random.rand(n) * 360 - 180})
```

#### # Speed test 1 (Use `haversine`)

```py
df['diff'] = df.apply(lambda row: haversine(loc1, (row['latitudeE7'], row['longitudeE7']), unit=Unit.MILES), axis=1)
```

```
9.9 s ± 172 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

#### # Speed test 2 (Use `haversine_vector`)

```py
df['diff'] = haversine_vector(loc1, df, unit=Unit.MILES, comb=True)
```

```
105 ms ± 1.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

### Reference:

- `haversine_vector`: [document](https://github.com/mapado/haversine#combine-matrix)
- `haversine_vector`: [implementation](https://github.com/mapado/haversine/blob/main/haversine/haversine.py#L105-L159)